# According Catholic theology, what does the joy of heaven consist of?

Tags: catholicism, heaven

According Catholic theology, what does the joy of heaven consist of?

If there is a principal joy, what is it?

---

*Anecdote:* I remember riding on a bus and a man going of saying to the effect that if heaven consisted of praising God for all eternity, it could wait.

Comment: Is there an overarching theme behind this question and the other question you asked about hell? Maybe you should ask the central question.

Comment: @DoubleU No sure what you mean.